# calculate mean or variance for subset of pandas DF column

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a gigantic pandas DF with a bunch of columns in it. I want to calculate mean and variance for a subset of three columns. Is there an easy way to do this without creating a whole new dataframe? I get all NaN whenever I try to use something like this:

```
DF['means']=np.mean(DF.A, DF.B, DF.C)
```

or

```
DF['means']=DF[['A','B','C','D']].mean(axis=0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `DF[['A','B','C']].mean()` will give you the means, but it's one mean for each column.  There are only three numbers, so it's not clear what you want to happen when you try to make a new column with that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I am trying to create a fourth column that will show the row means for the existing three columns. So I want the mean of the values in row 1 for columns A,B,C of the DF; the mean of the values in row 2 for columns A,B,C of the DF; etc...

Comment: Okay, in that case the answer given below is correct.  `axis=0` means to take means that span rows (i.e., means going along columns), `axis=1` would mean to take means that span columns (i.e., means going along rows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not totally clear what exactly you want to do, but it looks like what you mean is taking the *per-row* average of columns A-D. In which case, you're just giving the wrong axis argument.

`DF['means']=DF[['A','B','C','D']].mean(axis=1)` should work fine.